# Delete after insert in SQL SERVER

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Is it possible to delete the row after the time ended? I have a query that going to insert the token then after amount of time, if its not used. The row token will be delete.

Here's how I only created my generator and connect to ajax to sql for now:

```js
function makeid(length) {
  var result = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
      charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}

const resulting = makeid(10)
console.log(resulting)
```

I used a `javascript` function connected to an `ajax` to insert the token to its owner.

Here's my query:

```js
string command1 = "insert into account_token(email, token) values (@email, @token)";

using(var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command1, con)) {
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@token", token);
  cmd1.CommandTimeout = 60;
  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

so basically the `"insert into account_token(email, token) values (@email, @token)"`
in is:

```js
INSERT INTO account_token(email, token) VALUES ('THE_EMAIL', 'THE_RANDOM_GENERATED_TOKEN')
```

Is using `Date.now()` is going to solve my problem?
PS: I'am using `asp.net c#`

Comment: `Is it possible to delete the row after the time ended?` what exactly you mean by this? When do you want to delete the token, what is the scenario and context?

Comment: Store timestamp along token and check token validity in queries. You may set up some timed task/job to remove aged tokens.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, The scenario is, when they clicked the forgot password on my html. An email will be sent to them along with the token, so after sending the token, the time starts as 15mins then. after 15mins when the token not used it will automatically delete

Comment: Another way, it can be handled, for instance, when you are sending the `token` you know the time when it has been created. Now the next step is the user will come and enter the token you had sent. In this step, you can check the token and its generated time let’s say if its older than your expected time then return a message to UI that `Token expired` and then delete the older token from the database. In this way, you don’t need additional service or any exe to check after a time interval whether the token expired or not. I think its more efficient and easy to implement.

Comment: Use MemoryCache for that purpose. [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Set expiration.

Comment: You need to implement a job scheduler. you can use Quartz or Hangfire but I suggest you use Quartz because its implementation is easier than Hangfire. then after you send an email to your client, you can call the job that you have described with a 15-minute cron and delete your record into the database.https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 1):

Add Expiretime Column in  account_token
You could create a SQL Job to run each day and execute a specified stored procedure for delete Expired Tokens

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx](https://%20http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx)

https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/377071/Delete-record-from-table-every-day-at-specific-time-using-SQL-Server-Job-Scheduler/